# I am confused with preposition "for"

Tags: prepositions

The example of "for":

> "This pool is for the use of hotel guests only".

I know that the key point of this sentence is "this pool is for hotel guests" and I understand it, but why "for the use of hotel guests"?

I am always confused when the "for" is before a thing or anything else except a person's name.

Comment: _for_ indicates _purpose_. Thus, _Calcium is good for bones_, _Exercise is good for body_, and so forth.

Comment: "This pool is for hotel guests [and nobody else] to use." Where does _with_ come into it?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, my bad, i forgot to edit the title